# How do I go about calculating protein concentration to make a set of protein standards for protein quantification via dot blot?

Tags: biochemistry

I have been given a protein of unknown concentration and have been asked to make a set of standards using a protein with a known concentration so we can quantify roughly via dot blot.

I need to know how to work out the calculation part. I would like to learn both mass and molar.For example, the information I have for my standard protein is it is at a concentration of 30mg/ml and 550uM. I want to put, for example, 1ul dots of this protein on the membrane for my blot. I want several dilutions of my standard, for example ranging from 20pg to 100ng. How do I work it out to get varied concentrations from the stock to my 1ul volumes on my blot?